# Regex Pattern matching json

Tags: json, regex, match

Given the following json string, how could I use regex to match just the values?

- input

  '{"a": {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"},"b": {"key3": "value3","key4": "value4"}}'
- output

  I need a regex to extract the values:

  '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}' and '{"key3": "value3", "key4": "value4"}'

Comment: You don't need to use `regex` in this case, but by the way which language do you use to get the values Js or Python?

Comment: Not only is it easy to do with a JSON parser, it's also impossible to do right with regex (maybe with perl's regex, but not with JS' nor python re's). For a python JSON parser check the [json module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html), for JS check [parse and stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally, I use

```
(\{[^{}]+\})
```

It works.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression is the wrong tool for this problem.

With JavaScript, this is very easy:

```js
const original = '{"a": {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"},"b": {"key3": "value3","key4": "value4"}}';
const updated = JSON.stringify(Object.values(JSON.parse(original)));
console.log(updated);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your input is a JSON string, you can parse it into a dict with `json.loads` and then dump it again with `json.dumps` after obtaining the dict values (assuming your input is stored in variable `j`):

```
import json
print(json.dumps(list(json.loads(j).values())))
```

This outputs:

```
[{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}, {"key3": "value3", "key4": "value4"}]
```

If you're using Python 3.6 or earlier versions, where dict order is not guaranteed, you can use the `object_pairs_hook` parameter with `collections.OrderedDict` as the object pair resolver:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
print(json.dumps(list(json.loads(j).values()), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict))
```